# How to Compute peak point form polygon object

Tags: geometry

[image]

---

I have to transform the first object (Polygon object) to the second. In order to transform the object to flat surface I need to compute the Height $H$ from the curved line. I am looking for the formula to compute it.

Measurements are given in the form of a polygon array

[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],[x3,y3,z3],[x4,y4,z4],[x5,y5,z5],[x6,y6,z6], .....

Comment: put $ signs around math objects

Comment: "to flat surface": don't worry, it is already flat.

Comment: Find the corner $D$ by noticing the sudden tangent change. Then you can complete the $L$-shape. If those two curved sides are convex and monotonic (w.r.t. horiz & vert) as drawn, your $L$ will enclose the original curved polygon.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: By "flat" he or she likely means "straight" or "rectilinear."

Comment: You need to transform from left to right? Is it always L shape? Will not the max(x) two y values define H?